Find $f_{xy}(0,0)$ if $f(x,y)=xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$
Function
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}&&(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\0&&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$
is continuous at $(0,0)$.
How to find $f_{xy}(0,0)$ and $f_{yx}(0,0)$?
I tried to treat $y$ as constant to find $f_x$, then treat $x$ as constatn to find $f_{xy}$, but there is common factor $y$ at numerator, so when I substitute $(x,y)=(0,0)$ I got $0$. The same to $f_{yx}$.
I don't think I'm right because my colleague told me the answer is $\pm 1$ for these two partial derivative.

What have you tried?  Do you know how to define and compute a directional derivative?

Please show your attempt, at least write down the definition of $f_{xy}(0,0)$ and $f_{yx}(0,0)$.

edit the question to add more info.

$$f_{xy}(0,0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac 1{x-0}\left(\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(x,y)-f(x,0)}{y-0}-f(0,0)\right)$$

If $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, then $$\frac{\partial\left(xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)}{\partial x}=\frac{yx^4-y^5+4x^2y^3}{x(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
\begin{align}
f_x(0,0)&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0-0}{x}dx=0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
f_{xy}(0,0)&=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f_x(0,y)-f_x(0,0)}{y}\\&=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-y-0}{y}=-1
\end{align}
Leave $f_{yx}(0,0)$ to the reader.

Thanks very much. so I should use defination to find partial derivative at saddle point?

@LeoSHEN Yes, definitely.

@Leo SHEN Note that some books define $f_{xy}$ as $x$ goes first and then $y$, but some $y$ goes first. You should check which definition you are using.
